# Only one database logon allowed in crystal reports with asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, database-connection

**Database Logon Failed**

I am fade up with this error. I want to show my database records in crystal report. I am using the same procedure in my previous project and it's working fine. But when I am using the same procedure in other projects, it's not working. Following steps I am doing to display my database records in crystal reports.

1. Created a ado.net dataset with the name EmployeeDetails.
2. Created a DataTable with same name and structure as database.
3. Added a crystal report and selected the **"Project Data"** option at the time of connection and selected the dataset which I created in Step 1
4. Designed my Crystal report.
5. Then added a CrystalReportViewer in my aspx page and write the following code in page load.

   ```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
           if (!IsPostBack)
           {
               try
               {
                   ds = new EmployeeDetails();
                   string EmpCode = "PRD001"
                   ds = EmployeeCard(EmpCode); // Here I am fetching the records from database
                   string ReportName = "EmployeeCard.rpt";
                   ds.Tables[0].Merge(ds.Tables[0]);
                   int rows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                   rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(ReportName));
                   rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
                   CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Response.Write(ex.ToString());
               }
               finally
               {
                   rptDoc.Close();
                   rptDoc.Dispose();
               }
           }
       }
   ```

The above mentioned steps I used in my previous project and It's still working fine with no error. But When I am using the same steps to created crystal reports in my other projects. It is showing **Database Logon Failed** Error.

I wondered when I debug my program and didn't get any exception at any line. So I got a doubt **"Is it possible that only one connection allowed with database with crystal reports ?"**

Please help guys.

Comment: had you given correct login credetials?

Comment: Yes. No problem with fetching data from database.

Comment: database login failed is when it's incorrect user or password. make sure your crystal report itself isn't trying to connect to the database with remnant settings